# Rails validations and custom callbacks ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the below validations for one of my models. The goal is to validate presence of first_name, last_name, and shop. Then *after* (but still before validation), I want to run my custom validation :status.

```
  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name
  validates_presence_of :shop

  validate :status, :on => :create

def status
  do stuff with first_name and last_name
end
```

But it appears that :status is running before the other validations, so I am getting errors for nil first_name etc. How can I correct this?

Comment: Why do you need to run them in order? FWIW Rails runs all validations every time, even if one already failed.

Comment: before_create might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your custom validation to run if the other validations have come back as invalid, do this:

```
def status
  return if errors.present?
  do stuff with first_name and last_name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help. If `status` is a field in your table, you have to change the custom validate name. For instance

```
validates_presence_of :first_name
validates_presence_of :last_name
validates_presence_of :shop

validate :check_status, :on => :create

def check_status
  if first_name.present? && last_name.present? && shop.present?
    do stuff with first_name and last_name
    errors.add(:status, "you message here.") // if you need a error message
  end
end
```

For more information here [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods). Hopefully it can help you